# Why is Parsing XML and getting element not working for iOS 10.3.1?

Tags: jquery, ios, xml, angular, ionic-framework

With Ionic with Angular 2, I'm using jQuery to parseXML and get an element value.

Following is the XML I’m parsing to get the gameID.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:ev="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/event/" xmlns:s="http://sidearmsports.com/schemas/cal_rss/1.0/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"> 
 <channel>
  <title>2017 Baseball Schedule</title><link>Original link here</link>    
  <atom:link rel="self" href="Original link here" />
  <description> </description>
   <item>
    <title> Baseball at </title>
    <description>Baseball at …</description>
    <link> Original link here </link>
    <s:gameid>1234</s:gameid>
    <s:links>
     <s:livestats>stats go here<s:livestats>
    </s:links>
   </item>
   <item>
    <title> Baseball at </title>
    <description> Baseball at …</description>
    <link> Original link here </link>
    <s:gameid>1235</s:gameid>
    <s:links>
     <s:livestats>State go here<s:livestats>
    </s:links>
   </item>
 </channel>
</rss>
```

Following is the code I'm using for parsing:

```
this.http.get(urlToUse).subscribe((res) => {
  var response = res.text();
  response = response.replace(/^(\r\n)|(\n)/g,'');
  let parsedXML = jQuery(jQuery.parseXML(response));
  parsedXML.find('item').each(function() {
    el = jQuery(this);
    console.log("Schedule data");
    console.log("el");
    console.log(el.text());
    gameId = el.find('gameid');
    console.log("gameId");
    console.log(gameId);
    console.log(gameId.text());
  });
});
```

When I run on browser and any other iOS versions (except 10.3.1), the response text shows all the elements, GameId console also prints all the gameIds.

For the 10.3.1, it prints all the elements but gameId console prints an empty line.

'gameid' is the local name so it picks the right element everywhere. Tried replacing find('gameid') to find('s:gameid'). No luck!

Comment: Did you do any debugging? Maybe try to print 'title' or 'link' instead first.

Comment: @wannadream, thanks for your comment. Yes, all the other fields are getting extracted.

Comment: What is el.text() printing? Can you post the value?

Comment: @wannadream, thanks for your help. I was able figure out what the problem was. Starting 10.3.1, the paring didn't pick the tag's localname. Instead, there were being referred with their entire tag name. So, when I change find('gameid') to find('s//:gameid'), it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought this could help some folks who ends up in this situation!

In the above XML, each tag had it's own local name. Until iOS 10.3, when they were referred to, with their localname, their value was getting picked. The tags which didn't have namespace, matched with the existing localnames so they continued working.

Solution: Replace tags with namespaces from el.find('gameid') to el.find('x\:gameid').